# Present or future tense?

Tags: tenses

Is the following sentence in present or future tense?

> I will now begin.

**Context**
I was writing a speech, at the end of which I say: "My friend Steve* **will now** talk to you about..."

It seemed to me at first that it should be present, because of its usage of the word "now", but it makes more sense for it to be in the future (I *will* begin).

Comment: I know you think that's a meaningful binary question, but it really isn't: that's a modal auxiliary, which means the real question is whether it’s in the epistemic mode or in the deontic one. As for tense, that’s a lesser matter that doesn’t much apply here, but if you want to know, then here’s a hint... if you’ll please figure out the tense of *would* in “He said that he would now begin” then you’ll know the corresponding answer to your own question.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for your reply! I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm asking this question because I am trying to translate this phrase into a different language where the verb conjugation is dependent on the tense, and am unsure of whether to use future or present.

Comment: The only 'tensed' verb in your example is "will", which is present tense.

Comment: The construction itself uses the modal verb *will*, which can refer to present time or to future time. You have provided no context to determine which of these is in effect. The word *now* does not have to mean and rarely does mean, *right this very second*. As for tense, English doesn't have a future tense, just more than dozen ways of referring to future time.

Comment: @Clare I have added some context - does the meaning of "will" change in this situation?

Comment: *I will now talk about turtles* is something that happens in the future, albeit the immediate future. *I now talk about turtles* is interpreted as habitual; these days I tend to talk about turtles. *I am now talking about turtles* is present; something that is currently going on at this very moment.

Comment: @PeterShor That makes sense :D Thankyou!

Comment: *Tense* does not always correspond to the *time* when something happens. This is true for English as well as other languages (some  languages with a genuine future tense conjugation often use the present tense to talk about future time). "Now" in this context refers to the immediate future. English can  use several constructions to talk about the immediate future. The construction *will now talk* is the present tense but, in this context, 
 it's referring to immediate future time.

Comment: @Clare Ah, thank you for explaining the difference between the construction tense and the time. I understand _now_!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, there's a word that indicates the immediate past: *just*. If you want to say that you stopped talking about turtles very recently, you would say

> I just talked about turtles.

You can't say *I now talked about turtles,* although *I just now talked about turtles* is fine.

There is no corresponding common word for the immediate future, so we use *now* combined with *will* or *am going to* instead. So if you want to say you will start talking about turtles  very soon, you say

> I will now talk about turtles.

The present tense constructions in English don't work for this:

> I am now talking about turtles,

would imply that you have already started talking about turtles, and

> I now talk about turtles,

would probably be interpreted as habitual—these days I tend to talk about turtles.

Comment: I like your answer; it’s helped the asker, too, given that “accepted” checkmark. I wonder if the suggested choice of “use present tense” could be clearer. Clair makes a good point commenting how even languages with future-tense verb inflections can still use present tense for future events. Indeed translating to a Romance language—even one w/both periphrastic & inflected futures—I’d more likely use a simple present here (FR *Et maintenant je commence*; ES *Y ya comienzo*; PT *E já começo*) than even a periphrastic “I'm going to…” future—let alone an inflected one like *commencerai, comenzaré*.